# How delete a line having a word quickly in multiple large files using powershell

Tags: powershell

How delete a line having a word quickly in multiple large files using PowerShell

i am using the below code but it take long time

```
   $files = Get-ChildItem "D:\mjautomation\v19.0\filesdd\"

foreach ($file in $files) {
   $c = Get-Content $file.fullname | where { $_ -notmatch "deletethisline" }
   $c | Set-Content $file.fullname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be reasonably fast due to use of [`switch -File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch), but note that it requires reading each file into memory *as a whole* (minus the excluded lines):

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File D:\mjautomation\v19.0\filesdd) {
  Set-Content $file.FullName -Value $(
    switch -Regex -File $file.FullName {
      'deletethisline' {} # ignore
      default { $_ } # pass line through
    }
  )
}
```

If you don't want to read each file into memory in (almost) full, use a [`[System.IO.StreamWriter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter) instance, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984110/45375) instead of [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) to write to a *temporary* file, and then replace the original file.

Doing so has the added advantage of avoiding the small risk of data loss that writing back to the original file via in-memory operations bears.

---

If you want to make do with the - slower - [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet, use the following; the same caveats as above apply:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File D:\mjautomation\v19.0\filesdd) {
  Set-Content $file.FullName -Value (
    @(Get-Content $file.FullName) -notmatch 'deletethisline'
  )
}
```

---

Note that as an alternative to the `foreach` *loop* you can use a *single pipeline* with the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* - `Get-ChildItem ... | ForEach-Object { <# work with $_ #> }` - but doing so is slower (though in many cases that won't matter).